# Google Analytics API Reporting

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to make a report (readonly) form some account of which I have credentials only? I mean particularly without owner giving an access to the service account of the application.

I need to make a report from tens (maybe hundreds) accounts.

Answer (score 0):

A service account is necessary only when you want a serverside application to pull the data without logging in to the browser. With your own credentials you could e.g. use Google Spreadheets with the Analytics Add-on and set a schedule to query the accounts in intervals for current data (the spreadsheet runs with your credentials, so you do not need to log in to run the report). Or you can simply have the reports e-mailed to you, that's a build-in feature with GA.

So yes, if you have read access you can create reports.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that I really need to access these reports via PHP from serverside application. I need to get data (pageviews, sessions etc.) from GA campaigns and pair it with other DSP.